# Could someone explain the jquery .select() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked at the docs and I'm having trouble other finding information on this method, I think it handles an event where text is added or changed in a text input or text area. however, cant get it to work. I'm hoping someone can further explain this event handler to me.

```
<input id="first" type="text">// if something is typed here an event should be triggered
      //at least if my understanding is correct which it clearly isnt
<input id="second" type="text">//hello should appear here when the event is triggered

<script>
       $("#first").select(function(){$("#second").val("hello")})//this does nothing
</script>
```

Comment: **[`This is an official information about .select()`](https://api.jquery.com/select/)**

Comment: You have some syntax errors. Look at your console to see them (right click on page and click Inspect Element). Reload the page and you will see errors.

Comment: Otherwise it should work as expected. The event is triggered when you select text inside the textbox, not when you just type text. Also, you should put a hash sign in front of "second" in your javascript code. It should be like this: `$("#first").select(function(){$("#second").val("hello"); });`

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. If you actually want to do something when text is changed or added, you probably want to use the [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.select()` works when you select text inside of a text or textarea element. Meaning when you "highlight" text with the mouse. Try it below:

```js
$("#first").select(function() {
  $("#second").val("hello");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>First:</div>
<input id="first" type="text" value="select this text">
<div>Second:</div>
<input id="second" type="text">
```

If you want to hook into additions, you can use something like jquery's `on input` instead:

```js
$("#first").on('input', function() {
  $("#second").val("hello");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>First:</div>
<input id="first" type="text">
<div>Second:</div>
<input id="second" type="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the **[`official documentation of jquery for .select()`](https://api.jquery.com/select/)**, here's definition for what it does and an example to demonstrate.

**Official Description**

> Bind an event handler to the "select" JavaScript event, or trigger
>   that event on an element.

which means you are trying to do some operation of targeted element when you `select` text in source element. Watch out the comments for what it's doing.

```js
//always good to wrap events inside document.ready
$(function() {
  $("#first").select(function() {
    //once you perform select operation on input#first element either by Ctrl+a
    //or by Mouse drag event
    $("#second").val("hello");
    //value of input#second element should be updated to hello
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first" type="text">
<input id="second" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the `select` method. It is used when text in an input element is selected. Your comments indicate that you want the code to be triggered when something is typed.

For that, you should use the `input` event if you want to trigger a function when input is received in the element.

Also, your function didn't include a `#` in front of the `second` reference, so you were not correctly accessing that element.

```js
$("#first").on("input", function(){
  $("#second").val("hello")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first" type="text">
<input id="second" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<input id="first" type="text">
<input id="second" type="text">
<script>
$("#first").change(function() {
    $("#second").val("hello")
})
</script>
</body>
```